# Best practice to wait for a change with Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

After a click event I need to wait for an elements attribute to change before proceeding further (click event causes certain elements to move out of focus and certain others get focus via a JS)

After spending time searching for a reliable alternative to "waitForAttribute" (selenium 1 command) in web driver... I could get the below code to work. But I am not sure if this is the best implementation...

Any other better solution??

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(wedriver1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
.....
button.Click();
wait.Until(webdriver1 => webdriver2.webelement.GetAttribute("style").Contains("display: block"));
```

Also, can anyone please share a link to how I can handle AJAX event changes using webdriver.

Comment: http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/ has a nice listing of possible wait methods and how they relate

Comment: @Pat: the assertselenium.com website seems to be gone.

Comment: Archived versions of that page: http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://assertselenium.com/2013/01/29/webdriver-wait-commands/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a recurring problem of Selenium.
I am not sure about a "best" implementation existing. I believe it's largely depending on the situation.

Concerning AJAX-driven changes, I would generally use a waitForElementPresent or a waitForElementNotPresent depending on the changes the AJAX call will make on the page.

Comment: This will work, but only for situations where an element appears/disappears. There are many situations where an element remains visible but changes an attribute, which I think the OP was asking for, which these methods don't cover.

Answer (score 9):

I suggest use `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(WebElement element, String attribute, String value)`.

e.g.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5); // time out after 5 seconds
someElement.click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(someElement, "sort-attribute", "ascending"));
```

([docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html))

Answer (score 4):

You can use implicit WebDriver wait :

> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

More here: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.html#implicit-waits

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you understood my question. My elements attribute changes on a click event (driven by JS). I don't see how the implicit wait is useful here. From my understanding implicit wait is more relevant in case of elements being visible after an event.

Answer (score 2):

I feel that using the WebDriverWait is pretty useful. One change you can make in your code is use -

```
webelement.isDisplayed();
```

instead of getting the style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Thread.sleep like people have implemented [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201425/wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-complete-with-selenium-2-web-driver).You can use their implementations to relate to your problem.

```
    public void waitFor(Webdriver driver,,WebElement welElem, String attributeValue){
    int timeout=0;
    while(true){
        if(driver.webElem.getAttribute(attribute)!=null){
        break;
        }
        if(timeout>=10){
        break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
        timeout++;
    }

}
```

I think you could implement something like this. I have not checked it but you get the idea.

Comment: I believe this whole while loop is what the "wait.Until" I posted above is doing. So I don't see the point of writing this explicit while loop. I suppose my implementation which is working is a lot cleaner

Comment: `while(timeout<10)` and delete `if` statement. Just a note to your code.