# Parse text that is constantly updated using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python

On: http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=96823302, we need to take the problem out of the `problem` tag in the `<span>` class.

It is constantly updated, how can I retrieve the data out each time using BeautifulSoup/Python?

I know it will be like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=96823302").content)
problem = soup.find("span",class_="problem") #Initial finding

a = True
while(a == True):
  print problem
  problem = soup.find("span",class_="problem")
```

//Then it will re-loop

But this only prints out: `<span class="problem"></span>` not the inside like `2 + 2` or `2 x 2`

Comment: problem generated at runtime by javascript  use `selenium` package [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: So like: content = driver.find_element_by_class_name('problem')?? But this wont parse the text though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426321/best-practice-to-wait-for-a-change-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: although you can probably just wait for a few seconds for a non existant div and then try and get the contents of the problem span ... it should take almost no time for the js to populate the problem... see also http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/webdriver-wait-for-text-to-be-present.html