# is it possbile to locate an element created by javascript using webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In firebug, I used element inspector to locate an element, and then use the name of that element to locate the element in webdriver by function of findElementByName, but it complains it can't find that element. The element is transformed by javascript, as I can't find it using "view page source". So is it possible to locate such element in webdriver?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you post HTML of the element you want to target?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide some more details at least the html?

What I am assuming that you have to wait until your javaScript finish loading. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201425/wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-complete-with-selenium-2-web-driver)
if your application use jQuery. And then find the element using attribute. In that case you have to be perfect with the selector.

Something like this should work I am thinking.

By.CssSelector("[type='checkbox']") //attribute = attribute value