# jQuery is undefined inside document.ready

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium-webdriver

I am checking in my selenium script if ajax calls are completed, in which I first check if document is ready then check if jQuery is defined and then check active status

```
public class WaitForAjaxToLoad {
public static void waitForAjaxToLoad(WebDriver driver) {

        final JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        ExpectedCondition<Boolean> e = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

               if(js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"))
               {
                    if((boolean) js.executeScript("return window.jQuery != undefined")) {
                      Boolean status= (Boolean) js.executeScript("return jQuery.active==0");
                      System.out.println("Jquery is defined active status:"+status+"for thread:"+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        if (status) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("jQuery is undefined for thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                        return false;
                    }
               }
               else {
                   System.out.println("Document is not ready for thread "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                   return false;
               }


            }
        };  
         wait.until(e);

 }
}
```

When I execute my script , document is ready but jQuery is undefined.
This happens when test method is executed in parallel.
Why do i get jQuery is undefined once document is ready?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15791319/954442) for Java, your test could be greatly simplified - without, in my view, losing anything valuable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return js.executeScript("return jQuery.active == 0");
    }
});
```