# How to wait until my browser will get into time out using selenium

Tags: java, selenium

So i have perform some times tests using `Selenium`:

My page have simple `Drop Down List` and from this `Element` i am selecting different value and wait until the next page will load and calculate the time that this operation took and again try to load different value from this `Drop Down List`.
So in some values this took a loot of time (because the page need to load many thing) so in this case sometimes this lead into white screen and in this case i want to specify that this is `TimeOut` so my question is how to recognise that this white screen appears when i cannot expect to any `WebElement` on this white screen.

Comment: After selecting any value from dropdown add a expected wait condition to verify for a web element to be displayed on the next page.if the web element is not dispayed after mentioned time selenium will throw an exception and you can catch it using try catch.  Have a look at below sample code.    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id<locator>));

or

Comment: I am using this wait in any element i want to fine with specific conditions but in this case i want to recognise browser timeout

Answer (score 0):

You can `waitForCondition` to wait until a particular javascript condition is true. There's also other `waitForX` convenience methods.

https://www.neustar.biz/blog/selenium-tips-wait-with-waitforcondition

Note: If using jQuery you can wait for `"jQuery.active == 0"`

[wait for an ajax call to complete with Selenium 2 web driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201425/wait-for-an-ajax-call-to-complete-with-selenium-2-web-driver)

Comment: I am using this wait in any element i want to fine with specific conditions but in this case i want to recognise browser timeout